# Normalize quantum state

Tags: vectors, quantum-computation

There are given two vectors describing quantic state:

$$
x=
\begin{pmatrix}
e^{j^{30^\circ}}\\
1+2j
\end{pmatrix}
$$

$$
y=
\begin{pmatrix}
3+j\\
e^{j^{60^\circ}}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
How to normalize them so i'm able to calculate tensor product like:
$$
\hat x \otimes \hat y
$$

It's confusing because of the "e" component which is obscure for me.

Comment: What do you mean by: $\|x\|\otimes\|y\|$? To my knowledge $\|x\|$ usually represents the norm of the object $x$, and the tensor product $\otimes$ takes two tensors and produces a higher-order tensor. In your case you appear to be passing it two scalars? Do you just mean: $x \otimes y$?

Comment: I wanted to calculate tensor product of normalized x and y. I have only some notes from school, maybe is some missing. Please be tolerant, this is my first question on math exchange.

Comment: By normalized $x$ and $y$, do you mean: $\hat{x} \otimes \hat{y}$, where $\hat{x} \triangleq \frac{x}{\|x\|}$ and $\hat{y} \triangleq \frac{y}{\|y\|}$, or $\|x\| = \sqrt{x_{1}^{2} + x_{2}^{2}}$? Welcome to Math StackExchange, I'm not trying to be rude, just trying to find the root of your question so I (and others) can help better! :)

Comment: By normalized i meant and understand (experience with 2d graphics) that it's vector with length=1, the problem is i can't understand the "e" component at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following on from your comments, I believe that what you want to compute is the Tensor product:

$$\hat{x}\otimes \hat{y}$$

Where $\hat{x}$ and $\hat{y}$ are unit vectors (i.e. $\|\hat{x}\| = \|\hat{y}\|=1$), defined by:

$$\hat{x} = \frac{\vec{x}}{\|x\|}, \qquad \hat{y}=\frac{\vec{y}}{\|y\|}$$

We note that we can define the norm $\|\cdot\|$ in $\mathbb{C}^{2}$ using the following:

$$\|\vec{x}\| = \sqrt{\left|x_{1}\right|^{2}+\left|x_{2}\right|^{2}}$$

So we can calculate, (where $j$ is the imaginary unit $j = \sqrt{-1}$):

$$\|\vec{x}\|=\sqrt{\left|e^{j\cdot 30^{\circ}}\right|^{2}+|1+2j|^{2}}=\sqrt{1+5}=\sqrt{6}$$

Where we have used [Euler's Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula): $e^{j\theta} = \cos(\theta) + j\sin(\theta)$, thus giving us $\left|e^{j\theta}\right| = 1$ for all $\theta$. So we can write our normalized $\vec{x}$ vector:

$$\hat{x}=\frac{\vec{x}}{\|\vec{x}\|}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}\begin{pmatrix}e^{j \cdot 30^{\circ}} \\ 1+2j\end{pmatrix}$$

And for $\vec{y}$:

$$\|\vec{y}\|=\sqrt{|3+j|^{2}+\left|e^{j \cdot 60^{\circ}}\right|^{2}}=\sqrt{11} \implies \hat{y} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{11}}\begin{pmatrix}3+j \\ e^{j \cdot 60^{\circ}}\end{pmatrix}$$

We therefore have that:

$$\begin{align*}\hat{x}\otimes \hat{y} &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{66}}\begin{pmatrix}e^{j \cdot 30^{\circ}} \\ 1+2j\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}3-j & e^{-j \cdot 60^{\circ}}\end{pmatrix} \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{66}}\begin{pmatrix}(3-j)e^{j \cdot 30^{\circ}} & e^{j \cdot 30^{\circ}} \\ 5+5j & (1+2j)e^{-j \cdot 60^{\circ}}\end{pmatrix}\end{align*}$$

Where we have used that in $\mathbb{C}^{n}$ we have:

$$\vec{x} \otimes \vec{y} = \vec{x}\vec{y}^{\dagger}$$

Comment: This is clear now. Thank You!